# Trouble with hashsets in java

Tags: java, getter

I'm unsure on how to create a getter and setter method for my class file that uses a hashset of strings. Am I right on saying since there is no indexing with hashsets a getter method would return the whole set and that a setter would simply add an element to the set?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Names {

    // fields 
    private final Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    //methods 
    public void addNames(final String name) {
        names.add(name);   
        System.out.printf("Added %s to names hashset%n", name);  
    }

    // getter methods 
    public Set<String> getNames () { 
        return names; 
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Names n = new Names();

        n.addNames("Roger");
        n.addNames("Gary");
        n.addNames("Mark");
        n.addNames("Sue");
        n.addNames("Angela");
        n.addNames("Jay");
        n.addNames("Peter");

        System.out.println(getNames());   

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? printing the contents of the HashSet?

Comment: Why do you want to even create the `Names` class? What purpose does it solve? You can simply create a `HashSet` called names in the `main()` method which would do the exact same thing.

Comment: it depends on your implementation,  you can have a field of type Set and then can create setter for the field. The users of your class can pass new HashSet <String >() using the setter method. If you wish to add elements then you can use as you have already done.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I guess it depends on what you want to achieve. Getters and setters are used to modify and retrieve field values, so strictly speaking you would have a setNames and getNames - but then what would be the purpose of your class? As another person explained, you could rather use a hashset directly.

Comment: Also the way I have been asked to write this program is by using classes and objects. Which is by I'm not just doing it all in the main method.

Comment: you can access set value using iterator.and if you know names you have added you can filter data too `for (Iterator<String> it = names.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String f = it.next();
        if (f.equals(new String ("Hello")))
            System.out.println("String found");
    }`

Comment: If this is homework--and that's fine--please tell us what the assignment is. Your assumptions aren't necessarily correct. You could add multiple names all at once if you wrote a setter (adder) to do that, and you could retrieve individual entries if you wished, depending on how you wanted the user to tell you which entry they wanted. So the answer is, "It depends". Tell us the assignment and we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right . For `Set<Names>` the way you have created the `addNames()` function is correct it behaves similar to that of Setter in this case. 
Getter is fine.

In order to prove this you can try to generate getter/setter of this object explicitly by using eclipse as well. It will also generate only getter.

For setting the value diff function is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but if the aim of the getter method is to return the whole set of names so that you can print it, then you're almost there.

Change `System.out.println(getNames());` to `System.out.println(n.getNames());`.